# Leaflet Layer Control for Multiple Layers in One Object

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I'm reading in a large JSON object that has multiple layers within the same object. The structure is like so:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "AllProgrammedProjects",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "ID": 2,
                "ProjectID": "0012506X",
                "ProjectNam": "I-26 over SC 302",
                "ProjectDes": "I-26 over SC 302 Bridge Replacement and Interchange Upgrade",
                "BudgetCate": "Operational & Safety",
                "ProjectTyp": "Interchange Improvement",
                "ProjectAct": "Design\/Development",
                "LocationLi": "Lexington",
                "Route_Leng": 1.4,
                "ROW_Year": 2003,
                "CON_Year": 2020,
                "DateOfCurr": "Currently Undetermined",
                "SCDOT_Cont": "Jae Mattox",
                "SCDOT_Con1": "MattoxJH@scdot.org",
                "LocationTy": "Road",
                "RouteLRS": "32010002600E",
                "SegmentBeg": 112.5,
                "SegmentEnd": 113.5,
                "RouteDescr": "I-26",
                "MPO": "COATS",
                "Status1": null,
                "Contact_Nu": "(803) 737-1805",
                "COUNTY_NAM": "LEXINGTON",
                "COG": "CENTRAL MIDLA",
                "PriorityCo": "BR-INTNHS"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [-85.534770830624609, 32.398104157650017],
                    [-85.534633972042457, 32.39791557487046],
                    [-85.534364899661909, 32.397537624044901],
                    [-85.534207535164825, 32.397302292846959],
                    [-85.534110830421426, 32.397130347856773],
                    [-85.534079221152481, 32.397070467667184],
                    [-85.533991311939118, 32.396903933123156],
                    [-85.53392699651333, 32.396769874052822],
                    [-85.533865093938445, 32.396632037137088],
                    [-85.533611878276488, 32.395955507469395],
                    [-85.533607289864804, 32.395943555374338],
                    [-85.53336872279246, 32.395322120767062],
                    [-85.533246923816222, 32.394986445677233],
                    [-85.533242719705569, 32.394975517690625],
                    [-85.533158934055976, 32.39475772823959],
                    [-85.533017038618539, 32.394388887688457],
                    [-85.532873115249615, 32.394004117977566]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "ID": 3,
                "ProjectID": "0012506X",
                "ProjectNam": "I-26 over SC 302",
                "ProjectDes": "I-26 over SC 302 Bridge Replacement and Interchange Upgrade",
                "BudgetCate": "Operational & Safety",
                "ProjectTyp": "Repaving",
                "ProjectAct": "Design\/Development",
                "LocationLi": "Lexington",
                "Route_Leng": 1.4,
                "ROW_Year": 2003,
                "CON_Year": 2020,
                "DateOfCurr": "Currently Undetermined",
                "SCDOT_Cont": "Jae Mattox",
                "SCDOT_Con1": "MattoxJH@scdot.org",
                "LocationTy": "Road",
                "RouteLRS": "32040030200E",
                "SegmentBeg": 21.6,
                "SegmentEnd": 22.0,
                "RouteDescr": "SC302",
                "MPO": "COATS",
                "Status1": null,
                "Contact_Nu": "(803) 737-1805",
                "COUNTY_NAM": "LEXINGTON",
                "COG": "CENTRAL MIDLA",
                "PriorityCo": "BR-INTNHS"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [-85.534229625011235, 32.395303407760039],
                    [-85.534068203756362, 32.395471291395936],
                    [-85.533775827800142, 32.395775271450432],
                    [-85.533585266326938, 32.395971459323647],
                    [-85.53342543040921, 32.396136412477311],
                    [-85.532948771123046, 32.396628334137674],
                    [-85.532915884039099, 32.396662314688776]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I wanted to create a leaflet layer group for each of the `ProjectTyp` in the object, how would I go about doing that? With this example, it would be two controls, one for `Interchange Improvement` and one for `Repaving`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for: http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/roads/plines.html

Your GeoJSON is from a file in the same folder as the HTML file. I called it roads.json, look for url variable on the page, If you're using a service, put the real url in there instead of the file name.

Next I created a layer1 and filtered it for "Repaving", and a Layer2 for the other.

Then added them into the layer control.

Look at working example above, right click view source to see my code.

```
var road1 = L.geoJson(null, {  
        color:'black',

        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            var popupContent = "<p><b>Project Name: </b>" +
            feature.properties.ProjectNam +
            "<br> Project Type: " + feature.properties.ProjectTyp + "</p>" ;

            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);

        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
            return (feature.properties.ProjectTyp == "Repaving" );
        }

    });

    // Add GeoJSON to road layer
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
       road1.addData(data);
    });

    //Add road layer to map
    road1.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, I forgot about the filter option in Leaflet!